# Integrate Shibboleth and spring security to make a webapplication act as a saml identity provider

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071967/how-to-use-spring-saml-extension-to-make-our-webapp-as-an-identity-provider) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071967/how-to-use-spring-saml-extension-to-make-our-webapp-as-an-identity-provider) stack overflow question, spring security can not act as a saml 2.0 identity provider.

As far as i understand, there are standalone products out there which can act as saml identity providers (shibboleth, simplesamlphp, etc).

What would be the approach to integrate spring-security and shibboleth so a spring application can act as an identity provider for a saml service provider?

I'm also wondering if there's a specific reason why there's no identity provider implementation in the spring-security extension available.