# Should I use Spring Security SAML, or Shiboleth SP when expecting multiple applications?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-saml, shibboleth

At our university, we are planning to host a range of separate small web-applications implemented in Spring Boot, hosted in a Tomcat web-container. Our university has a Shibboleth IdP that we would like to use to authenticate users.

What I understand up to this point, is that we need to host our own Service Provider, and that this can be done by integrating it into each separate application using [Spring Security SAML](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/), or by installing a Shiboleth Service Provider on the Tomcat server, and somehow map it to the applications [using this method](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPJavaInstall).

[This SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908548/single-sign-on-in-spring-by-using-saml-extension-and-shibboleth), and the answer by Vladimir, already clarified a lot, but I'd like to make sure I invest my time in the most appropriate way of setting this up for our specific use-case.

- Multiple small applications
- All applications use the same IdP, so the same authentication, but the authorizations (who can access what) might be different.
- We don't require customization to the login procedure. I would like to have the default look and feel the university uses on all its other applications.
- Preferably, I would like to keep the "who can access what" rules, *outside* of the applications.

Do I understand correctly that using Spring Security SAML, would become redundant, since I need to include it into each application, and configure it for each application? While using the Tomcat approach, I would only need to set this up once, and then just set up the mapping to the applications correctly?

Comment: Shiboleth  is noting but java implementation of SAML, so if you are looking to do this using Spring or any other framework(based on java) then you should use Shiboleth.

Comment: Oh, from what I understood from the latest (2015) documentation, Shiboleth SP is only implemented in C++: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPJavaInstall ("The Shibboleth SP is presently only implemented in C++ as a module for Apache httpd"). Isn't it exactly the Spring Security SAML module that is the Java implementation of SAML?

Answer (score -1):

For java implementation of SAML, you can take a look here.

[Shiboleth's open saml java](http://shibboleth.net/downloads/java-opensaml/)

or even you can try Spring's SAML implementation if you prefer

[Spring Security Saml](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/)

Do let me know, in case i missed something.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but I mention both links you provide explicitly in my own question already. Also, what question is your reply an answer to? I don't see how your answer relates to my question...