# Spring SAML Security Certificate Caching Issue

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-saml2

I am using Spring security SAML 1.0.3 Release version. I figured out a problem that if we upload a certificate for the IDP it does not get reflected in the Spring SAML.
The problem seems to be with **MetadataCredentialResolver**  where there is a cache Map

```
  Map<MetadataCacheKey, SoftReference<Collection<Credential>>> cache;
```

It is picking the certificate from the cache and hence the newer uploaded cert is ignored. Is there a way I can reset the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way to get rid of cache is to override a class and make it set the values to null for all the cache related calls:-

```
@Override
protected Collection<Credential> retrieveFromCache(MetadataCacheKey cacheKey) 
{
    //return null and let it fetch from metadata
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void cacheCredentials(MetadataCacheKey cacheKey, 
Collection<Credential> credentials) {
   //do not put anything into cache
}
```